# Can't post entity with one to one HAL link using Spring rest data mvc

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I try to save **Clinic** entity with OneToOne `nullable = false` relation with **User** Entity.

**Clinic Entity:**

```
//....Some fields
@OneToOne(optional=false,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private User user; 
//.. Getters & Setters
```

**User Entity**

```
//....Some fields
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
private Clinic clinic;
//.. Getters & Setters
```

- **Post User successfully.**

  ```
   curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"firstName" : "Khaled","lastName" : "Lela","userName" : "KhaledLela","password" : "128ecf542a35ac5270a87dc740918404","email" : "example@gmail.com", "phone" : "12345678","gender" : "MALE", "level" : "ADMIN"}' http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/user

  HTTP/1.1 201 Created
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Location: http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/user/4
  Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 12:26:41 GMT

  {
    "token" : null,
    "firstName" : "Khaled",
    "lastName" : "Lela",
    "userName" : "KhaledLela",
    "password" : "128ecf542a35ac5270a87dc740918404",
    "email" : "example@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "12345678",
    "gender" : "MALE",
    "level" : "ADMIN",
    "birthDate" : null,
    "createDate" : null,
    "updateDate" : null,
    "_links" : {
  "self" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/user/4"
  },
  "user" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/user/4"
  },
  "clinic" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/user/4/clinic"
  }
    }
  }
  ```
- **Can't Post Clinic with User link**

  ```
  curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"clinc","address":"address","city":"city","area":"area","user":"http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/user/2"}' http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/clinic
  ```

> List of constraint violations:[
>       ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=user, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.entity.Clinic, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
>   ]

- **Clinic Repository**

  ```
  @RepositoryRestResource(path = "clinic")
  public interface ClinicRepo extends CrudRepository<Clinic, Long> {}
  ```
- **Pom**

  ```
     <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
      <spring.data.jpa.version>1.11.1.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
  <spring.data.rest.webmvc.version>2.6.1.RELEASE</spring.data.rest.webmvc.version>
     </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.41</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Spring Rest Repository -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.data.rest.webmvc.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: You definately have a `setUser()` (or `getUser()`) method in Clinic?

Comment: @AlanHay OMG, IDE setter&getter generation missed `setUser() & getUser())` may be i added this property after generating getter&setter.
And it's working now after adding them.Thanks for your Kind help, really you saved my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **@Alan Hay**, My fault i missed to add `setUser() & getUser()` on **Clinic** entity.

After adding them worked like a charm,..

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"clinc","address":"address","city":"city","area":"area","user":"http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/user/2"}' http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/clinic

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/clinic/1
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 15:59:16 GMT

{
  "name" : "clinc",
  "address" : "address",
  "city" : "city",
  "area" : "area",
  "longitude" : null,
  "latitude" : null,
  "createDate" : null,
  "updateDate" : null,
  "doctors" : [ ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/clinic/1"
    },
    "clinic" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/clinic/1"
    },
    "user" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/clinicfinder/api/clinic/1/user"
    }
  }
}
```